# How to set timeout for SqlTransaction.Save()?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am getting:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Save(String savePointName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Save(String savePointName)
```

How to increase timeout of `SqlTransaction.Save()`?

Comment: Sounds like you might have a deadlock in your SQL, I don't think doing a `SAVE TRANSACTION` in sql normally takes too long.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Depending on size of the database and number of transactions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server, C#: Timeout exception on Transaction Rollback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977219/sql-server-c-timeout-exception-on-transaction-rollback)

Comment: @dotctor It's hard to test, as it occurs seldom. The referred question speaks about rollback and begin transaction.

Comment: @TN. I have been googling and also have been noticing a trend talking about  the [ConnectionTimeout on the connection object being used as the commmit timeout on a `SqlTransaction.Commit()`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26d54516-74b7-4a54-b879-85536e4b605f/where-to-set-the-timeout-for-a-sqltransactioncommit?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) however no mention of `.Save()` and the timeout. It might be worth a try. (Now I wish I did not encourage PSVSupporter to delete his answer)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have found this thread before, then I decided to create this question, to verify this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I really wished I had not encouraged PSVSupporter to delete his answer (if he undeletes it, please vote on him).

Internally when you make any transaction request the request uses the `ConnectionTimeout` property of the underlying connection as the `CommandTimeout` of the query.

You can follow this process in the source, the important part is in `SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon` and `SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionPreYukon` both pass `ConnectionOptions.ConnectTimeout` in to the `timeout` parameter to the functions that they call. So to solve your issue, use a larger `ConnectionTimeout` when creating the connection.

[SqlTransaction](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlTransaction.cs,f202e4e23449abef)

```
    public void Save(string savePointName) {
        //SNIP
                _internalTransaction.Save(savePointName);
        //SNIP
    }
```

[SqlInternalTransaction](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/sqlinternaltransaction.cs,666b105a54b6562c)

```
   internal void Save(string savePointName) {
        //SNIP
             _innerConnection.ExecuteTransaction(SqlInternalConnection.TransactionRequest.Save, savePointName, IsolationLevel.Unspecified, null, false);
        //SNIP
    }
```

[SqlInternalConnectionTds](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs,250ccd6f05f79cc8)

```
    override internal void ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, string name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, bool isDelegateControlRequest) {
        //SNIP

        if (!_parser.IsYukonOrNewer) {
            ExecuteTransactionPreYukon(transactionRequest, transactionName, iso, internalTransaction);
        }
        else {
            ExecuteTransactionYukon(transactionRequest, transactionName, iso, internalTransaction, isDelegateControlRequest);
        }
    }

    internal void ExecuteTransactionPreYukon(
                TransactionRequest      transactionRequest, 
                string                  transactionName, 
                IsolationLevel          iso, 
                SqlInternalTransaction  internalTransaction) {
        //SNIP

        Threading.Tasks.Task executeTask = _parser.TdsExecuteSQLBatch(sqlBatch.ToString(), 
             ConnectionOptions.ConnectTimeout, null, _parser._physicalStateObj, sync: true);

        //SNIP
    }

    internal void ExecuteTransactionYukon(
                TransactionRequest      transactionRequest, 
                string                  transactionName, 
                IsolationLevel          iso, 
                SqlInternalTransaction  internalTransaction, 
                bool                    isDelegateControlRequest) {
            //SNIP

            _parser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(null, requestType, transactionName, isoLevel,
                ConnectionOptions.ConnectTimeout, internalTransaction, stateObj, isDelegateControlRequest);

            //SNIP
    }
```

Comment: I understand, but PSVSupporter was not providing a prove of his answer. Since the timeout occurs really seldom, it's hard to check whether their answer is correct (maybe just accidentally true) or wrong. Thank you for the investigation.